# Android : Convert millisecond to time

Tags: android

I want return millisecond to time

But my code not work !

```
long ms = 86400000;

long s = ms % 60;
long m = (ms / 60) % 60;
long h = (ms / (60 * 60)) % 24;
String timeFind = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", h, m, s);
```

Comment: what is exact problem ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use `SimpleDateFormat`, but be aware that you should set both the time zone and the locale appropriately:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String text = formatter.format(new Date(millis));
```

The time zone part is important, as otherwise it will use the system-default time zone, which would usually be inappropriate. Note that the `Date` here will be on January 1st 1970, UTC - assuming your millisecond value is less than 24 hours.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
int seconds = (int) (milliseconds / 1000) % 60 ;
int minutes = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60)) % 60);
int hours   = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
```

Answer (score 1):

1 second= 1000 milli seconds... Try now
or if you are trying to retrive the current time you could use Calendar class

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String time =""+cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use my code simple and work for me

just call this function and put millisecond

```
    public String settIMER(int time) {
        String str = "00:00";
        try {
            long parseLong = time;
            if (parseLong >= 3600000) {
                try {
                    str = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d:%02d",
                            new Object[]{Long.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(parseLong)),
                                    Long.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(parseLong) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1)),
                                    Long.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(parseLong) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1))});
                } catch (NumberFormatException unused) {
                    java.lang.System.out.println(parseLong);
                }
            } else {
                str = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d",
                        new Object[]{Long.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(parseLong) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1)),
                                Long.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(parseLong) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1))});
            }
            return str;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "00:00";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [TimeUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) instead of do all that math, that way you make sure that this will actually work, and It's more readable.

#### Edit

Adding code example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(86400000)
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(86400000)
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(86400000)
```

Comment: Please post example code.

Comment: @SedJ601 good call, added it!